# Google Maps in android zoom error

Tags: android, google-maps

When zooming the map on the emulator, after a certain extent the emulator stops and I get this error in my logcat:

> distrib/android-emugl//host/libs/Translator/GLES_CM//GLEScmImp.cpp:glColorPointer:433 error 0x501

Is this error related to my code?

Here is the xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.subham.gmaps.details">

    <fragment
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/mapView"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

The code that generates the map:

```
public class details extends ActionBarActivity {

    public String sourceAddress;
    public String destAddress;
    public double lat1 = 0.0, lng1 = 0.0, lat2 = 0.0, lng2 = 0.0;
    GoogleMap googleMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_details);
        Intent i = getIntent();
        if(i != null)
        {
            sourceAddress = i.getStringExtra("source");
            destAddress = i.getStringExtra("destination");
            Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
            try{
                List<Address> sourceAddressList = geocoder.getFromLocationName(sourceAddress, 1);
                List<Address> destAddressList = geocoder.getFromLocationName(destAddress, 1);

                if(sourceAddressList.size()>0)
                {
                    GeoPoint p1 = new GeoPoint((int)(sourceAddressList.get(0).getLatitude()*1E6), (int)(sourceAddressList.get(0).getLongitude()*1E6));
                    GeoPoint p2 = new GeoPoint((int)(destAddressList.get(0).getLatitude()*1E6), (int)(destAddressList.get(0).getLongitude()*1E6));
                    lat1 = p1.getLatitudeE6()/1E6;
                    lng1 = p1.getLongitudeE6()/1E6;
                    lat2 = p2.getLatitudeE6()/1E6;
                    lng2 = p2.getLongitudeE6()/1E6;
                }
                createMapView();
                addMarker();
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Log.d("Exception", e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }


    private void createMapView()
    {
        try{
            if(googleMap == null)
            {
                googleMap = ((MapFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapView)).getMap();
                if(googleMap == null)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error creating map", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.d("Exception", e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private void addMarker()
    {
        if(googleMap != null)
        {
            googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(lat1, lng1)).title(sourceAddress));
            googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(lat2, lng2)).title(destAddress));
        }
    }
```

Here, first I get the location from the user (source and destination) in an activity and then pass those details to the next activity that calculates the latitude and longitude of the locations and generates the map. I have not modified any zoom settings. The map was zoom-able as such. What is the issue here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in this [issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=82997), disabling your host GPU should solve your problem when using the emulator.

Keep track of this issue for any fixes that might be released. Host GPU Support greatly increases your VM performance, and having to keep it disabled is the same as having a Lambo in your garage which you cant drive.

Comment: When deploying the app, there wont be any issues right?

Comment: Not at all. This is an AVD exclusive feature.